# psycopg2 Update Query broke up my PostgreSQL table

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

When I run this UPDATE query it breaks up my PostgreSQL table `messages`. Am no longer able to update the rows or the table so had to create a new table and delete the old one.

```
cursor.execute('''
        SELECT
            outbounds.messages.oubd_msg_pvt_uuid,
            outbounds.messages.oubd_ord_pvt_uuid,
            outbounds.messages.oubd_cont_pvt_uuid,
            outbounds.messages.oudb_sndr_pvt_uuid,
            outbounds.messages.end_phn_pvt_uuid,
            outbounds.messages.status          
        FROM outbounds.messages   
        WHERE outbounds.messages.status = false
    ''')
    records = cursor.fetchall()

    for row in records:
        print(row['sender'], ' -> ', row['number'], ' = ', row['content'])

        cursor.execute('UPDATE outbounds.messages SET status=true WHERE oubd_msg_pvt_uuid = %s', (row['oubd_msg_pvt_uuid'],))
        print(cursor.rowcount, "Record Updated successfully ")
```

And while it says that it was updated, in reality the row is not updated.

Am a newb to Python so now sure what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you commit the transaction?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe no. How? Is that why my table is messed up?

Comment: Maybe you should edit the question and explain what exactly you mean by "messed up".

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe It broke the table somehow. I wasn't able to update any of the rows or the table `messages` itself. After running a query in DataGrip I'd have to endlessly wait to no end. So I restarted the PostgreSQL service. And dropped the `messages` table and created a new one.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe `.commit()` seems to have solved the problem. Could you please explain a bit about why I need commit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you forgot to commit the transaction.

If you start a transaction in a relational database, all data modifications are not persistent until you end the transaction.

There are two ways to end a transaction:

- `COMMIT` makes the changes persistent
- `ROLLBACK` undoes all changes from the transaction as if it never happened

If you terminate the database session without committing, the transaction is automatically rolled back.

If your `UPDATE`s hang, there must be a concurrent open transaction that is holding a lock. Find it in `pg_stat_activity` and kill it with `pg_terminate_backend` using the `pid`.

If a restart doesn't take care of the lock, it may be a prepared transaction. Check in `pg_prepared_xacts` and use `ROLLBACK PREPARED` to remove it.

If all that does not do the trick, look into `pg_stat_activity` and check what the session is waiting for.

Comment: Right. But why did me not `COMMIT`ting broke the table?

Comment: You still didn't explain what you mean by a broken table. Are there any error messages?

Comment: No error messages. I am able to `INSERT`. But unable to `UPDATE`. Just an endless wait when a run an `UPDATE` both on a row and the table itself...until I cancel. And restart the entire PostgreSQL service from the command line because it's all stuck.

Comment: But a restart of PostgreSQL should kill the `pg_stat_activity` or not? Because the same problem persisted after a restart.

Comment: Added more. It might be a prepared transaction.